# Problem with \mathbf in xetex

Tags: xetex, fontspec, bold, unicode-math

I am using xelatex to typset mathematics documents in devanagari.  I have problem with `\mathbf`. I am using  velthuis font mapping.  In `\mathbf`, I am getting devanagari characters. But, usual math font is ok. Here is a MWE.

```
  \documentclass{article} 
  \usepackage{amssymb}
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \setmainfont[Script=Devanagari,Mapping=velthuis]{Annapurna SIL}
  \newfontfamily\eng{Times New Roman}
  \begin{document}
  yah ek
  udaaharan hai|| 
  {\eng This is a MWE.}     $\mathbf{i}$, $i$
  \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I experience no problems if I (a) load `unicode-math` instead of `fontspec` and (b) use `\symbf` instead of `\mathbf`.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\defaultfontfeatures{Path=/Users/mico/Library/Fonts/} % change this as needed
\setmainfont{AnnapurnaSIL-Regular.ttf}%
   [Script=Devanagari,Mapping=velthuis,
    BoldFont=AnnapurnaSIL-Bold.ttf]
\setmathfont{STIX2Math.otf} % or some other Times-compatible math font
   [Scale=MatchUppercase]
\newfontfamily\eng{Times New Roman.ttf}%
   [Path=/Library/Fonts/, % change this as needed
    Scale=MatchUppercase,
    BoldFont=Times New Roman Bold.ttf,
    ItalicFont=Times New Roman Italic.ttf,
    BoldItalicFont=Times New Roman Bold Italic.ttf]

\begin{document}
yah ek
udaaharan hai|| 

\textbf{yah ek
udaaharan hai|| }

{\eng This \textit{is} \textbf{an} \textbf{\textit{MWE.}}} 

$i$, $\symbf{i}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Aside: I use MacTeX2019, with all the latest updates installed. Externally acquired fonts, such as Annapurna SIL and Stix Two Math, are stored in `/Users/mico/Library/Fonts` in my system; they will (of course!) be placed in other locations on other systems.

Answer (score 2):

Using unicode-math and `\symbf` as suggested by Mico is imho the right and best solution as you will get the correct unicode chars.

But to explain the concrete problem: `fontspec` by default maps the main text font to `\mathrm`, but as your main font uses a mapping you get the wrong output.

You could load fontspec with the `no-math` option, then it will use the default Latin Modern fonts for the `\mathXX` commands instead. Or you could reset `\mathrm` to whatever you prefer:

```
\documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{amssymb}
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \setmainfont[Script=Devanagari,Mapping=velthuis]{Annapurna SIL}
  \setmathrm{Annapurna SIL}
  \newfontfamily\eng{Times New Roman}
  \begin{document}
  yah ek
  udaaharan hai||
  {\eng This is a MWE.}     $\mathbf{i}$, $i$
  \end{document}
```

[image]