# Follow up question to "Problem with \mathbf in xetex" (question 522628)

Tags: xetex, bold

This is a follow up question to [Problem with \mathbf in xetex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/522628/)

I tried Micos solution.  It works. I have another problem now.  The entire text seems to be in bold. I can't spot the problem. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\defaultfontfeatures{Path=/usr/share/fonts} % change this as needed
\setmainfont{AnnapurnaSIL-Regular.ttf}%
[Path=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/annapurna/,Script=Devanagari,Mapping=velthuis,
BoldFont=AnnapurnaSIL-Bold.ttf]
\setmathfont{STIX2Math.otf} % or some other Times-compatible math font
[Path=/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/stix2-otf/,Scale=MatchUppercase]
\newfontfamily\eng{Times_New_Roman.ttf}%
[Path=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/, % change this as needed
Scale=MatchUppercase,
BoldFont=Times_New_Roman_Bold.ttf,
ItalicFont=Times_New_Roman_Italic.ttf,
BoldItalicFont=Times_New_Roman_Bold_Italic.ttf]
\newfontface\Bigdn{AnnapurnaSIL-Bold.ttf}[Script=Devanagari,Mapping=velthuis-roman-numerals,Scale=1.4,Path=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/annapurna/]
\begin{document}
        {\Bigdn yah ek udaaharan hai||}
    {\bfseries yah ek udaaharan hai||}
    1
        {yah ek udaaharan hai||}
    {\eng This is a MWE.}
    $\symbf{i}$, $i$ $x^2+2x$ 
\end{document}
```

*EDIT* I am posting another MWE witout paths:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{unicode-math} % change this as needed
\setmainfont{AnnapurnaSIL-Regular.ttf}%
[Script=Devanagari,Mapping=velthuis-roman-numerals,
BoldFont=AnnapurnaSIL-Bold.ttf]
\setmathfont{STIX2Math.otf}[Scale=MatchUppercase]
\newfontfamily\eng{Times_New_Roman.ttf}%
[Scale=MatchUppercase,
BoldFont=Times_New_Roman_Bold.ttf,
ItalicFont=Times_New_Roman_Italic.ttf,
BoldItalicFont=Times_New_Roman_Bold_Italic.ttf]
\newfontface\Bigdn{AnnapurnaSIL-Bold.ttf}[Script=Devanagari,Mapping=velthuis-roman-numerals,Scale=1.4]
\begin{document}
        {\Bigdn yah ek udaaharan hai||}
    {\bfseries yah ek udaaharan hai||}
    1
        {yah ek udaaharan hai||}
    {\eng This is a MWE.}
    $\symbf{i}$, $i$ $x^2+2x$ 
\end{document}
```

The problem is the text 'yah ek udaharan hai' looks the same with or without \bfseries command.
*Edit* I was using a custom map file to get roman numerals instead of sanskrit numerals.  I have replaced it with the standard map file.  This will make it possible to reproduce the results.

Comment: Using all this Path settings makes your example quite unportable. Normally this shouldn't be needed, simply the file names should work. Is times really named `Times_New_Roman.ttf` on your system?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, in Linux.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer How do I add BoldFont= etc, if I don't specify the path. Please help.

Comment: Path is only needed if you are using special locations.  For the standard pathes it should work if you simply remove this setting.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Happy New Year...

Comment: A few tips not directly related to your bug. First, you don’t need to define `amssymb` if you load `unicode-math`. It will be overwritten and have no effect.

Comment: I’m not sure why you load `Script=Devanagari` and then use transliteration into the Latin alphabet.

Comment: You probably want to scale all your fonts to the same base height and add `\Huge` or whatever to `\Bigdn`. Or possibly a `relsize`.

Comment: You probably want to select languages with `babel` or `polyglossia`.

Comment: The only portable way to load Times New Roman is by its display name. Other Linux distributions name the file something else.

Comment: You can use `\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale = MatchUppercase }` to save yourself some typing.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer:
If I do this, letting `fontspec` automatically choose the sub-fonts:

MWE

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{unicode-math} % change this as needed
\setmainfont{Annapurna SIL}%
[Script=Devanagari,Mapping=velthuis-roman-numerals,
]
\setmathfont{XITS Math}[Scale=MatchUppercase]
\newfontfamily\eng{Noto Serif}%
[Scale=MatchUppercase,]
\newfontface\Bigdn{AnnapurnaSIL-B.ttf}[Script=Devanagari,Mapping=velthuis-roman-numerals,Scale=1.4]
\begin{document}
        {\Bigdn yah ek udaaharan hai||}

    {\bfseries yah ek udaaharan hai||}

    { yah ek udaaharan hai||}

    1
        {yah ek udaaharan hai||}

    {\eng This is a MWE.}

    $\symbf{i}$, $i$ $x^2+2x$ 
\end{document}
```

I get this:

[image: bold and not bold works OK]

I cannot reproduce the problem with my fonts (Windows); using `Annapurna SIL Bold` or `AnnapurnaSIL-B.ttf` gives the same result for `\Bigdn`.

Comment: I used a custom map file. I have now replaced it with the standard map file. It should be possible to reproduce the problem now. Thanks.

Comment: @S.Venkataraman I still cannot reproduce the problem. I confirmed with and without the mapping file. This may sound like a strange question: on your system, when you open the Annapurna regular font file in a font preview/viewer, is it bold, or regular? The description of the problem sounds like the bold version of the font has been set to be the main font. The `\bfseries` is enclosed in braces, so it is not that causing the problem. When you type text *before* the `\bfseries`, is that bold too?

Comment: @S.Venkataraman Even from version 1.0001, the files have been called `AnnapurnaSIL-B.ttf` and `AnnapurnaSIL-R.ttf`. The ones on your system have different names. Are they modifications, or do you have a Font Manager app running on your system? As if the files have been mixed up. Try a different font (Noto Serif Devanagari, e.g.; or just any ordinary font) - does the problem persist?