# Using Libertine math fonts with Vollkorn text font

Tags: fontspec, unicode-math, libertine, newtxmath

I'm making a Beamer presentation and would like to use the very elegant Vollkorn fonts. Vollkorn doesn't have good math support, so I'd like to find a not-incongruous replacement. The Libertine font family have similar serif weights, and are hypothetically available for math using `\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}`, but I just can't quite get it to work. Another constraint that will become relevant is that I'd like to render white-on-black text on some slides.

I'll be partially following [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/522628/28304) which suggests `\usepackage{unicode-math}` and replacing `mathbf` with `symbf`, so I've replaced `\symbf` with a dummy command when demonstrating `\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}` for comparison.

I'm also using `\usepackage{textgreek}` so I can substitude text-rendering of some Greek characters to achieve desired styles.

I'll be compiling with `pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22`, which has ok unicode source handling by default. I'll be comparing these to the output of `XeTeX 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993`. I installed this using the TexLive package on Ubuntu, version 2021.20220204-1.

## Options when using `pdflatex`

### newtxmath + default fonts

With `pdflatex`, using only `\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}` without `\usepackage{libertine}` pulls in OT1 fonts, which aren't pretty. The command `mathbf` is broken. Also, the serif weights here won't work with white-on-black text for any font weight. Notice that no glyphs are missing (pdflatex finds an OT1 substitution when needed)

```tex
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
```

[image: pdflatex newtxmath default]

### newtxmath + libertine fonts

With `pdflatex` and both `\usepackage{libertine}` and `\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}`, we get a range beautiful styles, which are congruous with the body text and similar between Latin and Greek. I think the only difference here is that its using the Libertine main-text font to substitute missing glyphs, rather than OT1. Still, the serif weights won't work here for white-on-black, and I'd love to have some Vollkorn to spice things up.

```tex
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
```

[image: pdflatex newtxmath libertine]

## Options when using `xetex`

### Xetex with newtxmath

#### Using default fonts

The first thing we notice when switching to `xetex`, using `\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}` with the default fonts is that several glyps are missing. Now, it is `\boldsymbol` that is broken rather than `\mathbf`. Pixel-wise, it's not too different from pdflatex.

```tex
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
```

[image: xetex + newtxmath + default]

#### Using libertine fonts

In xetex, `\usepackage{libertine}` with `\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}` is slightly broken. It substitutes computer modern fonts in some places and is overall inferior to the output from `pdflatex`.

```tex
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
```

[image: xetex + newtxmath + libertine] fonts

### Xetex with `\usepackage{unicode-math}`

Note: `\usepackage{unicode-math}` isn't compatible with `\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}`.

With the default fonts (not shown), `\usepackage{unicode-math}` is not nice. Glyphs are missing and font substitutions look out of place. Compared to `\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}`, the command `\boldsymbol` breaks.

```tex
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
```

Adding `\usepackage{libertine}` (below) gives some improvements, but still has missing glyphs. Compared to `pfdlatex` with `newtxmath`, the command `\boldsymbol` is broken. You may also notice that the weight of the descender on the text μ is slightly lighter. In my opinion the rendering by `pdflatex+newtxmath` is more compatible with the style of the Latin text characters.

```tex
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
```

[image: xetex unicode libertine]

## Adding the Vollkorn font

As far as I know, the Vollkorn font requires these two magic lines

```
\usepackage[]{fontspec}
\setmainfont[BoldFont=Vollkorn Bold, BoldItalicFont=Vollkorn Medium Italic, Numbers={Proportional,Uppercase}]{Vollkorn}
```

The packate `fontspec` doesn't work with `pdflatex`, so we'll be stuck with `xetex` or `luatex` here.

As you can see below, `\usepackage{unicode-math}` is *really* bad with Vollkorn. This is unsurprising, because Vollkorn has no math support.

```tex
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage[]{fontspec}
\setmainfont[BoldFont=Vollkorn Bold, BoldItalicFont=Vollkorn Medium Italic, Numbers={Proportional,Uppercase}]{Vollkorn}
```

[image: xetex+vollkorn+unicode]

Removing `unicode-math` and adding `\usepackage{libertine}` and `\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}` doesn't quite work either: It's substituting OT1 fonts sometimes, which look wrong.

```tex
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[]{fontspec}
\setmainfont[BoldFont=Vollkorn Bold, BoldItalicFont=Vollkorn Medium Italic, Numbers={Proportional,Uppercase}]{Vollkorn}
```

[image: xetex libertine newtxmath vollkorn]

So, this is all quite frustrating.

- Vollkorn fonts are really nice, but fontspec restricts us to xetex/luatex
- Vollkorn doesn't support math, so we need another option. the OT and CM fonts are not congruous. The `unicode-math` package is often suggested, but doesn't really work.
- Libtertine math has similar serif weighs and `\usepackage{libertine}` with `\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}` works beautifully in `pdflatex`. But, this doesn't play nice in `xetex` once we add Vollkorn.

I'm assuming one option would be to do some very specific tweaking of the math styles, using various commands about which I know not. If you haven't guessed by now, there is another solution I found while writing this question, which I will post as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The final permutation, which I arrived on after exhaustive search, is to use `fontspec` to pull in the Vollkorn font, then use `\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}` *without* importing `\usepackage{libertine}`.

```tex
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[]{fontspec}
\setmainfont[BoldFont=Vollkorn Bold, BoldItalicFont=Vollkorn Medium Italic, Numbers={Proportional,Uppercase}]{Vollkorn}
```

[image: solution]

Of course, this still leaves much to be desired:

- `\mathbf` and `\operatorname` don't work on Greek.

  - With `\usepackage{libertine}`, it was possible to match styles by inserting text glyphs.
  - Now, the Vollkorn font is used. Bold does *not* look good, but standard medium-weight Vollkorn might stand in for bold Libertine in a pinch.
- The Libertine font works really well in `\text` mode for styling math, Vollkorn not so much. I'm really missing the bold μ.

I'm sure there's some way to make `xetex` default to Libertine text and not Vollkorn text within math environments, *without* breaking the `\mathbf` and `\operatorname` commands, but what is it?

Comment: I suppose you could look at that question, which's my take on a somewhat similar problem:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/690151/is-this-a-valid-fontspec-solution-for-using-arbitrary-fonts-in-math-text